# Два соединения - это плохо?

Tags: php

connection.php - здесь подключение к базе

one.php

```
require('connection.php');
```

two.php

```
require('connection.php');
code
$mysqli->close(); // закрыли подключение из connection.php
require('one.php');
$mysqli->close(); // закрыли подключение из one.php->connection.php
```

Comment: Может это и не плохо - только зачем? Зачем закрывать соединение, если оно потом опять потребуется?

Answer (score 3):

PHP всегда представляется одним файлом, так что все подключаемые php-модули могут "общаться".

Comment: одним файлом ?